# Showing bits in objects

Tags: enums, c++-cli

I'm reading a book about C++. The author shows this enum:

```c
[Flags] enum class FlagBits{ Ready = 1, ReadMode = 2, WriteMode = 4,
EOF = 8, Disabled = 16};
FlagBits status = FlagBits::Ready | FlagBits::ReadMode | FlagBits::EOF;
```

and he says that status is equals to '0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1011', but when I write status to console:

```c
Console::WriteLine(L”Current status: {0}”, status);
```

it shows: 'Current status: Ready, ReadMode, EOF'. How can he know it, and how can I write status to console to show its binary form?

Comment: If the author shows **that** enum definition, then you're not reading a book about C++, you're reading a book about C++/CLI -- these are two entirely different languages.

Comment: @ildjarn Here's the book which I'm reading: http://www.amazon.com/Ivor-Hortons-Beginning-Visual-2008/dp/0470225904/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1308601643&sr=8-1

Comment: I've not read that book, but given that it appears to cover both C++ and C++/CLI, at the very least **you** should be aware that the code you've shown isn't C++.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should look into [System::Convert::ToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.tostring.aspx)

```
int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    FlagBits status = FlagBits::Ready | FlagBits::ReadMode | FlagBits::EOF;

    Console::WriteLine(L"Current status: {0}", System::Convert::ToString( ( int ) status, 2 ) );
    Console::ReadLine();

    return 0;
}
```

Output: Current Status: 1011

Edit: if you want the empty zero 'padding' just do:

```
Console::WriteLine(L"Current status: {0}", System::Convert::ToString( ( int ) status, 2 )->PadLeft( 32, '0' ) );
```

If you want it segmented into byte size pieces, then just split up the result and insert space / hyphens.

Comment: BTW why there are all those 0's?

Comment: @Cobold because you have an integer with bits 1 ( Ready ), 2 ( ReadMode ) and 4 ( EOF ) specified. The same reason the leading zeros are empty is the same reason bit 3 is empty, there are no values.

Answer (score 4):

The first thing will be to cast the value to an integer. I'm not sure of the best way to do this in C++/CLI, but in C it would be `(int)status`.

C++ does not offer a way to display a value in binary, but it does allow hexadecimal. Here's the statement for that:

```
Console::WriteLine(L"Current status: {0:x}", (int)status);
```

The output should be `0000000b`.

Comment: @Cobold: use `{0:x8}`. Sorry for the omission. The spec is at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#XFormatString

Answer (score 2):

First, the author knows that because `status` is being OR'ed with the three enum values

```
FlagBits::Ready = 1 // Binary 0001
FlagBits::ReadMode = 2 // Binary 0010
FlagBits::EOF = 8 // Binary 1000
```

Just add these three values together and you'll get the `1011` the author talks about (you can truncate all leading zeroes). If you didn't come accross bitwise operations by now: The pipe `|` is used to do a bitwise OR-Operation on the values. You just add up all digits that are `1` like this:

```
 0001
 0010
+1000
-----
=1011
```

Second: Like my previous poster, Mark Ransom, I don't actually know if C# is capable of printing values in binary form like the "oldschool" `printf()` function in C or the `std::cout` in C++ are able to. First thought would be to use the `BitConverter` class of .NET and writing such a binary-print-function myself.

Hope that helps.

EDIT: Found an example here using the `BitConverter` I mentioned. I didn't check it in detail, but on first looks it seems alright: http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/33292766/print-a-number-in-binary-format.aspx

Comment: Do you know how to print it with the std::cout?

Comment: Best you take the attempt mentioned by @Brandon Moretz below my answer. The `Convert::ToString()` Method is the way to go :)

Comment: Oooops, sorry, I am actually mistaken: `printf` and `std::cout` also seem to only support hex representation and no binary formatting. I am truly sorry for this misleading comment, but the `Convert::ToString` mentioned by @BrandonMoretz is still the best choice for C++/CLI, which you are using.